# How to port C++ code to C++/CLI in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-cli

I have an application written in native C++ which I'd like to get running on the .NET virtual machine. I was thinking of recompiling the C++ code as C++/CLI, using the Visual Studio 2008 compiler. Regrettably, I don't find any documentation on how to do this, so hence my questions:

- Does this actually make sense? Am I trying the impossible?
- Where can information on the topic be found?

Comment: There is very little C++ code that cannot be translated into IL.  I only know of __fastcall.  Metadata is an issue but easily bypassed with traditional header files.  Just flip the switch, the compiler will complain.

Comment: I'm sorry to bump an old question, but I don't recognize the acronym IL, and searching for it along with related keywords yields lots of job results from Chicago :\ What does IL mean?

Comment: IL is more specifically CIL, for Common Intermediate Language. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language. If you are reading MSDN docs, look for CLR, for Common Language Runtime. (CIL code runs on CLR platform, so both are referring to what you want.) In Visual Studio 2010, New Project / C++ / CLR / Windows Form  App (or whatever). In VS 2012, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130915/windows-form-clr-application-in-visual-studio-2012-rc for what to do, if you need Windows Form with your C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lot of native C++ code will actually just compile and run on C++/CLI. This is really a kind of *hybrid* compiler that can call native Win32 functions and use standard C libraries like OpenGL. You can even call COM interfaces directly (all the stuff you can do with a native C++ compiler).

The .Net library is also available but for these you create managed classes (using the **ref class** keyword). You will use **gcnew** to allocate memory for these classes (from a garbage collected heap). Memory for your normal classes is still allocated using **new** and **delete** (from a standard, non garbage-collected heap).

In short, you can migrate to .Net in bits and pieces, though there is still some friction when switching between managed and unmanaged classes.

I found this book useful: [Pro Visual C++/CLI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210532).

Answer (score 7):

Go to project properties -> General -> Common Language Runtime support -> change to /clr

It's called CLR now. Read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s(VS.80).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302048.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you can simply recompile your codebase with /clr. This technique called IJW (It Just Works) so you can easily use your existing classes with CLR.