# Is C++ CLR Windows Forms Application giving all the benefits of C++ and C# combined?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, clr

If I choose to create a C++ CLR Windows Forms Application, does that mean that I am able to use the entire C++ set as well as all the C# .NET libraries?

I am sorry if the question sounds stupid, but I would really like to know if I should use CLR or not.

Comment: I honestly think of it as C# giving the benefits of C++ and Java combined. My opinion may be biased, but C++/CLI seems a bit pointless compared to C#.

Comment: There is no such thing as "C# .NET libraries".  C# is a language, .NET is a framework.  C++ CLI gives you access to the framework and the CLR, it has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: I'd recommend using C# and leaving C++/CLI for glue code for native interoperation (which is what it was intended for).

Comment: @chris: C# is a great language, don't get me wrong, but it hardly gives you the benefits of C++.  I'll take C# over C++ in a heartbeat for tasks which suit it well, but in my day job (systems engineer) C# is simply not an option.

Comment: Well, considering you *can't* use the entire set of C++ abilities in safe/partial-trust managed code (e.g. pointers) , the answer would be "no".

Comment: @EdS., I agree that C++ has many uses that C# can't fulfill, but it's very productive for the things that have been covered.

Comment: @chris: Of course.  C# is my go-to language for UI's which don't require a lot of calls into native components.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts on this. So, in the end I understand that a C++ CLR application limits the some of the capabilities that a C++ Win32 application would have.

Comment: Chocolate is great and becon is great, but it doesn't mean you should eat it together.

Comment: What are you tying to do that you cannot do C# .NET or have performance issues in C# .NET?

Comment: @Lol4t0 Bad example. Chocolate covered bacon is delicious.

Comment: @Blam I am not trying to do anything specific yet, but I do know of some C# limitations regarding drawing/animations. I only wanted to know if I can get the best of both worlds if I work with C++ CLR projects.

Comment: *I object closing this topic. Actually a lot of newbies start their projects with `c++-cli` and then get a lot of troubles. One can here make guide when you should/should not use `cli`* @PeterRitchie, then make your own. I'm not good in English common dishes) I could make more sound example, but It would be Russian-specific))

Comment: @LeeGriggs: In Visual studio 2012 RC, microsoft removed the option to make a windows form clr application, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130915/windows-form-clr-application-in-visual-studio-2012-rc) and are not recommending it for making new UI applications in the future.

Comment: @Lee - You lose the power of native C++ without gaining the advantage of the C# development environment. No advantage at all, really.

Comment: @Bo Persson : "You lose the power of native C++." Why ???

Comment: @Lol4t0 . Hallo ! Please I want to read wath you have to explain. Po ruskii ia toche poinmaiu ;-)

Comment: @Peter Ritchie: "considering you can't use the entire set of C++ abilities in safe/partial-trust managed code (e.g. pointers)" What do you meand?? I use it apparently whithow problems.

Comment: @qPCR4vir - Lee wanted to get all of C++ and C# combined, but that does not happen. You loose parts of C++ without gaining all of C#. Not a very good compromise.

Comment: Thanks!! What I want to know is : what part of C++ you loose?

Comment: @qPCR4vir, C++ is _very_ complex language to learn, C# is _either complex_ in another way. With c++-cli you get a mix of this two languages. If you know exactly, why you have chosen c++cli, it is OK to use it. But then you will not ask _this kind of questions_. When you are not very good in c++ and c# you will lose yourself in c++-cli completely. It has two different types systems (managed and unmaneged). It has two standard libraries (one from c++, another from .Net). When combining .Net and c++, c++-cli not only get their benefits, but their troubles also. You'll have to deal with it.