# No more C++ WinForms projects?

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, visual-c++

So I've downloaded VS 2012 and VS 2013 Ultimate and am trying to create a new C++ Windows Forms project. The option's always been there but I've mainly been writing C# apps for a while now. Where have the C++ WinForms project templates gone? Can we not create C++ WinForms projects anymore? How do we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the template was removed from 2012 and 2013.  Refer to Tim 't Hart's answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130915/windows-form-clr-application-in-visual-studio-2012-rc) for a possible workaround.

Comment: Thanks, I am checking that out now.

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm. Only took a few seconds, too. Thank you @Michael :-)